# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, javabeans

I am new to jsp and I am trying to run a test file using javabeans in jsp on tomcat 6. Here is the code for main.jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using JavaBeans in JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<center> 
<h2>Using JavaBeans in JSP</h2> 
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="action.TestBean" /> 
<jsp:setProperty name="test" property="message" value="Hello JSP..." /> 
<p>Got message....</p> 
<jsp:getProperty name="test" property="message" /> 
</center> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the code for javabean TestBean.java

```
/* File: TestBean.java */ 
package action; 
public class TestBean
{
private String message = "No message specified";
public String getMessage() {
    return(message);
}
public void setMessage(String message)
{ 
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

When I try to run main.jsp on localhost, I get following error:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:161)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.main_jsp
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Did place the file TestBean.class in WEB-INF/classes/action/? And restart Tomcat?

Comment: yes I did. Still same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501829/unable-to-load-class-for-jsp

Comment: Went through that. My code doesn't contain scriptlets, as you can see.Deleting the work cache didn't help either.

Comment: The problem is with the JSP compilation / loading, not with the bean. What exact version of Tomcat are you using? Have you upgraded or otherwise changed the JSP compiler (ECJ)?

Comment: I am using tomcat 6.0 and haven't upgraded it.

Comment: I changed to tomcat8.0 and now it works. Thanks.