# IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 with Tomcat 6: Unable to load class for JSP

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat6

I have a web application with following directory structure:

```
  my-app
    [...]
    resources
      login.jsp
    [...]
    web
      [...]
      WEB-INF
        web.xml
```

When I try to run the application on Tomcat6, I get following errors:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:161)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.login_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

I read the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501829/unable-to-load-class-for-jsp) by BalusC, who suggested that this error might have been caused by a syntax error in the Java code inside *login.jsp*. But the file in question does not contain any Java code.

How can I fix this error?

**Update 1:** I found following message in the logs:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /login.jsp(6,0) The absolute uri: 
http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the 
jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:300)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:333)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:442)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the error by copying the *jstl-1.2.jar* file to the *lib* directory of Tomcat.

Comment: Wonder how to do the same with Jetty? Fix the same error, e. g.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(1,64) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application